# Calculating the area of a triangle defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, vectors

> In $\mathbb{R}^3:$
>
> $$A = (2,0,-1)\\ B = (3,1,-1)\\ C = (4,-2,0)$$
>
> Calculate the area of the triangle defined by $ABC$.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, I usually perform an orthogonal projection to calculate the height of the triangle, and then

$$\frac{b\cdot h}{2}$$

It is not entirely clear to me how to do the same for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Well, let's do it either way:

Cast an orthogonal projection of $\vec{AC}$ over $\vec{AB}$:

$$Proj_{\vec{AB}}\vec{AC} = \frac{\vec{AC} \cdot \vec{AB}}{\vec{AB} \cdot \vec{AB}}\cdot \vec{AB}$$

$$\frac{(2,-2,1)\cdot (1,1,0)}{(1,1,0) \cdot (1,1,0)}\cdot(1,1,0)$$

$$\frac{0}{2}\cdot(1,1,0)$$

$$(0,0,0)$$

Huh, a null projection... Maybe I can't do it this way after all?

Comment: What you've done is prove that $AC\perp AB$. You were on the right track, you just didn't work your solution through (I presume you were trying to brute-force the $\frac{1}{2}bh$ area formula). The general formula that you were looking for was: $$\frac{1}{2}||AC-\text{proj}_{AB}{AC}||||AB||$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work makes no sense. The area is zero if $\vec{AC}\perp \vec{AB}$?? Also, dot returns a scalar and you are taking dot of a scalar with a vector.

The best way is $\frac 1 2|\vec {AB} \times \vec {AC}| $

Answer (score 1):

Awesome's answer is pretty economical.  If you're in the mood, a much more masochistic way would be to use the Pythagorean theorem to find the side lengths of the triangle, then apply [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

Comment: Or take components of your area vector. Compute area of three projections separately and then take their resultant. $3$ times masochistic.

Comment: One might also calculate $\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}$, normalize it as well as $\vec{AB}$, and multiply them to get an orthogonal base which puts the triangle into the $XY$ plane of a new coordinate system. Decompose vectors and *voila*, the problem is reduced to $\mathbb R^2$, which has a known solution.  ;)

Comment: Or manually count every pixel inside the triangle!